# How to check programmatically if data roaming is enabled/disabled?

Tags: android

I'm trying to check if the user has enabled/disabled data roaming. All I found so far is that you can check whether or not the user is currently IN roaming, using TelephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming() and NetworkInfo.isRoaming(), but they are not what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can request the state of the Roaming-Switch via

```
ContentResolver cr = ContentResolver(getCurrentContext());
Settings.Secure.getInt(cr, Settings.Secure.DATA_ROAMING);
```

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#DATA_ROAMING

Answer (score 8):

Based on Nippey's answer, the actual piece of code that worked for me is:

```
public Boolean isDataRoamingEnabled(Context context) {
    try {
        // return true or false if data roaming is enabled or not
        return Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DATA_ROAMING) == 1;
    } 
    catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        // return null if no such settings exist (device with no radio data ?) 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's _Settings.Global.DATA_ROAMING_ from API 17.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static final Boolean isDataRoamingEnabled(final Context application_context)
{
    try
    {
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT < 17)
        {
            return (Settings.System.getInt(application_context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DATA_ROAMING, 0) == 1);
        }

        return (Settings.Global.getInt(application_context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DATA_ROAMING, 0) == 1);
    } 
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated function to account for API deprecation. It is now replaced with:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#DATA_ROAMING

```
public static boolean IsDataRoamingEnabled(Context context) {
    try {
        // return true or false if data roaming is enabled or not
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DATA_ROAMING) == 1;
    } 
    catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Settings.Global.DATA_ROAMING** now throws SecurityException for target SDK 33 or above. For API 33 and above you can use TelephonyManager.isDataRoamingEnabled.

TelephonyManager.isDataRoamingEnabled requires one of the following permissions: `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` or `Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` or `Manifest.permission.READ_BASIC_PHONE_STATE`

For more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#isDataRoamingEnabled()

```
public static boolean isDataRoamingEnabled(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        boolean hasFeature = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_DATA);
        return hasFeature && telephonyManager.isDataRoamingEnabled();
    } else  {
        final ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        return android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(
                contentResolver,
                android.provider.Settings.Global.DATA_ROAMING,
                0) == 1;
    }
}
```